# How to convert string to date format when string has only two digits for a year (Oracle, Netezza)

Tags: database, string, oracle, date, netezza

I have this issue databases: on Oracle and Netezza.

ISSUE: I have a string: 16101211213. This string means: YYMMDDHH24MMSS. I need to convert it to date format YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS. So on the way I need to add the two digits (in front of the string). I know that dates are for XXI century. So I need to 20 at the begining.So in result I should get 2016-10-12 21:12:13

Can anybody help me with it? I have tried many options (mainly on Netezza) but could not figure it out.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and share your attempts

Comment: Sorry, But I don't know what's wrong with this question.... I searched the topics related and couldnot find the solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RR might be your savior.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> with test as (select '16101211213' datum from dual)
  2  select to_date(datum, 'rrmmddhh24miss') result
  3  from test;

RESULT
-------------------
12.10.2016 11:21:03

SQL>
```

Oh, and - be careful! You used wrong format mask for minutes; it is "MI", not "MM" (which is a *month*).

[EDIT: displaying result using a different format mask]

```
SQL> with test as (select '16101211213' datum from dual)
  2  select
  3    to_date(datum, 'rrmmddhh24miss') result_1,
  4    to_char(to_date(datum, 'rrmmddhh24miss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') result_2
  5  from test;

RESULT_1            RESULT_2
------------------- ----------------------
12.10.2016 11:21:03 10/12/2016 11:21:03 AM

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, however it works properly in a half (on Netezza).
when I run the query:
'SELECT  
to_date (TISTAMP, 'yymmddhh24miss') 
FROM TABLE'
in results I have:
2016-04-22 00:00:00 for TIMESTAMP '160422181600'. Time is cut off.
Any idea why?
And apart from that: how the database knows that the year should be 2016? but not 1916?

thx

Comment: @mikikiki - this preserves the time; how are you running/displaying this? Maybe Netezza is pulling it as an 'ANSI' date and losing the time - does using `to_timestamp()` make any difference? (Also... using YY in the format masks makes them all the current century, which seems to be what you want; using RR treats years above 49 as being in the last century. It may not matter for your data.)

Comment: @Littlefoot - your query works on Oracle, on Netezza on the other hand works this: `to_timestamp(TISTAMP_VDA, 'yymmddhh24miss')`. which convers date to 2015-07-07 20:33:38 which is great!!! BTW: `rr` does not work on Netezza.  One more question, if I may, while now I have a date format my additional question is how to change the position of part of the date to have like MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS? Changing mask does not help here.

Comment: @miki kiki, I modified my message, have a look; basically, it is the TO_CHAR function which should be applied to the result of previous one (TO_DATE) in order to display the result as you want it. Other than that, you should modify NLS settings and set a different (default) format mask.

Comment: @mikikiki if this answer worked for you, please mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can either reply on Oracle inferring the year by converting with the YY or RR [format model elements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A), or concatenate the century value and use YYYY.

If you are really sure that the dates are all in the 21st century then using concatenation and YYYY:

```
to_date('20' || tistamp, 'yyyymmddhh24miss')
```

will behave the same as using YY (which uses the current date to decide the century):

```
to_date(tistamp, 'yymmddhh24miss')
```

and if all the years are below 50 then RR ([which uses the current date's century or the last century depending on the supplied 2-digit year](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F)) will also get the same result:

```
to_date(tistamp, 'rrmmddhh24miss')
```

But if any of the values are 50 or above RR and YY/YYYY behave differently. As these seem to be event timestamps it's unlikely they will be in the future, but the difference may still matter one day. (But then, eventually, assuming 21st century might not be valid either...)

Quick demo of the difference, using your sample value and a couple of others, supplied via a CTE:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

with your_table(tistamp) as (
  select '16101211213' from dual
  union all select '491231235959' from dual
  union all select '500101000000' from dual
)
select to_date('20' || tistamp, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') as yyyy,
  to_date(tistamp, 'yymmddhh24miss') as yy,
  to_date(tistamp, 'rrmmddhh24miss') as rr
from your_table;

YYYY                YY                  RR                 
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2016-10-12 11:21:03 2016-10-12 11:21:03 2016-10-12 11:21:03
2049-12-31 23:59:59 2049-12-31 23:59:59 2049-12-31 23:59:59
2050-01-01 00:00:00 2050-01-01 00:00:00 1950-01-01 00:00:00
```

All of these would also work with `to_timestamp()` of course; as you don't have fractional seconds or time zone info using dates should be fine as long as your client knows that Oracle dates have a time component.

Comment: hello, thanks, it works on Oracle. On Netezza does not work `rr`. Do you have an idea how to change a posiotn of date component in a date(to have Month on 1st position)? Changing mask does not help.

Comment: I don't know anything about Netezza *8-) I think you';re asking how to make Netezza format the date/time in a particular way - I have no idea how to do that. You could, possibly, convert the date to a string in the specified format, using that mask; but not sure if that's supported, and it can affect how things are displayed (re-ordering results, for instance).